# About distance of a point from a set

Tags: general-topology

Consider a subset D of normed space X and y is a  vector which is not in D. So we find distance of y from set D say this distance is '£' . Now i read that if set D is closed then we take guarantee that '£'  is always positive means  £>0.  So i think if D is not closed( Open) then is  there any possibility that £ =0  as y is  not in D and if yes then how. I thing a lot about it. But  not  found any solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $D$ is open then the distance between any point of the boundary of $D$ and $D$ is zero, with the boundary defined as

$$\partial D:=\overline D\setminus D^\circ$$

where if $D$ is open then $D=D^\circ$, with $D^\circ$ being the interior of $D$ and $\overline D$ the closure of $D$. Then

$$d(x,D)=0,\quad x\in\partial D$$

and obviously $x\notin D$ by the above definition. Example: let the open set of the real line (with the standard topology) $(0,1)$, then

$$d(0,(0,1))=d(1,(0,1))=0$$

and $0\notin (0,1)$, and $1\notin(0,1)$.

Comment: While we find the distance of y from D we find the distances between y and  each point of D. And take infimum of this. Now D is open so while finding the distance why i choose boundary points of D???

Comment: @samankumar I dont understand your question. The distance between any point of the boundary of $D$ and $D$ is zero, that is $$d(x,D):=\inf\{d(x,y):y\in D\}=0, \quad\forall x\in\partial D$$

Comment: Sorry my mistake ....my doubt is clear from your give example thanks....

Comment: @samankumar you are welcome, you dont need to sorry. Without error there is no learning.

Comment: Can you tell me pleass in above question if £>O then how i make sequence in D which converge to £

Comment: I arrange the sequence in decreasing order(in term of distance) and thing possible converge to £  but not able to prove it mathematically

Comment: @samar you have an already stated $\mathcal L>0$ for some pair $x,D$, so it is assumed that this sequence exists. Or you want to prove that the distance $\mathcal L$ is greater than zero for some pair $x,D$?

Comment: If i assume that £>O then how we say that sequence exist converge to £. How we prove it mathematical

Comment: @samankumar it depends on the topology where you are working on. For the standard topology on $\Bbb R$ we can say that if $x\notin[a,b]$ then $d(x,[a,b])>0$... but I cant use a sequence to show that because we dont have defined point $x$ or defined set $[a,b]$, I prove it using the fact that $x>b$ or $x<a$.

Comment: Friend forget about above question , now i have set D and y is point   whose distance from D is £>O . Now i see in my book that by the defination of infimum   there exixt a sequence which converge to £ . i want to prove this....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55132/discussion-between-masacroso-and-saman-kumar).

Comment: On what's app...... I am greatly thanks to you if you help me.... I use whats app or tell me any mode by which you can do chat

Comment: Saman, I dont have whats app, sorry (yes, I live in this way).

Comment: So how we can communicate...tell me by what mode... I am ready

Comment: Saman, open a new question in this site instead of using the comment, someone will help you.

Comment: Thankz @masacroso  i need a good helper to strong mu base.. I am belonging to a poor family. And can't afford fec. Of higher universities. Can you help me.. Or give me any advise. I have a lot of intrest in mathematics.....